# DigestValue the same for different input XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-signature

I am trying to sign an XML file, but not the whole file, just all inside tag "soapenv:Body". 
                                                                                    They gave me an example and I am trying to gt the same result, but to start off with I cant get the same DigestValue.
  The one that I am getting doesnt change, no matter what the input is, I thought if I changed the value inside a tag I would get a different DigestValue everytime, but I am not.
I need to know what I am doing wrong.
The code is the following:

```
                    doc.Load(xmlfileInput);  
                    XmlNodeList nodo = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body");
                    string nodoxml = nodo.Item(0).InnerXml;
                    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
                    //doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                    doc1.LoadXml(nodoxml);

                    //Print content to sign
                    System.Console.WriteLine(doc1.OuterXml);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    SignedXml signer = new SignedXml(doc1);
                    byte[] pkBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(privateKey); //testkey.key

                    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters pkFactory = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey(passwordKey.ToCharArray(), pkBytes);
                    RSA key = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(pkFactory);
                    signer.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                    signer.KeyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue(key));
                    signer.SigningKey = key;
                    signer.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigCanonicalizationWithCommentsUrl;
                    Reference r = new Reference("");

                    XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform(@"/dodas");
                    r.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
                    r.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

                    r.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

                    signer.AddReference(r);
                    signer.ComputeSignature();


                    System.Console.WriteLine(signer.GetXml().OuterXml);

                    XmlNode nodeimported = doc.ImportNode(signer.GetXml().FirstChild.ParentNode, true);

                    doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("dodas").Item(0).AppendChild(nodeimported);

                    string xmlFirmado = doc.OuterXml;
                    File.WriteAllText(xmlfileOutput, xmlFirmado);

                    //Éxito
                    System.Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Documento XML firmado con éxito!");
```

Two different runs show the following in the console:
  The first output:

```
        <mat:altaDoda xmlns:mat="http://impl.service.qrws.ce.siat.sat.gob.mx/siatbus/matce"><dodas><credenciales><!--Optional:--><ciec>
    <!--Optional:--><Usuario>TEST1TEST1</Usuario>
    <!--Optional:--><Contrasena>VMH94111</Contrasena></ciec>
<!--Optional:--><sellado><!--Optional:--><cadenaOriginalAA>kldffIL</cadenaOriginalAA><!--Optional:--><certificado64>kk9rtreljd</certificado64><!--Optional:--><firmado>||jkjkkkk|trtvl76767|jnkj3444||</firmado><!--Optional:--><serie>1234567890</serie></sellado></credenciales><!--1 or more repetitions:--><doda><!--Optional:--><datosGenerales><!--Optional:--><aduana>170</aduana><!--Optional:--><seccion>170</seccion><!--Optional:--><caat>123</caat><!--Optional:--><contenedores><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><contenedor><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><candados><!--Optional:--><valorCandado>valCandado01</valorCandado></candados><!--Optional:--><valorContenedor>valContenedor01</valorContenedor></contenedor></contenedores><!--Optional:--><idTransporte>890zxc</idTransporte><!--Optional:--><fastId /><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><tipoOperacion>1</tipoOperacion></datosGenerales><!--Optional:--><pedimentos><!--1 or more repetitions:--><pedimento><!--Optional:--><patenteAutorizacion>3904</patenteAutorizacion><!--Optional:--><documento>7100164</documento><!--Optional:--><numeroRemesa>2</numeroRemesa><!--Optional:--><dtaNiu>abc</dtaNiu><!--Optional:--><importeDifDolares>abc</importeDifDolares><!--Optional:--><importeEfectivoDolares>abc123</importeEfectivoDolares><!--Optional:--><umc>abc</umc><!--Optional:--><articulo7>0</articulo7><!--Optional:--><cove>12345</cove></pedimento></pedimentos></doda></dodas></mat:altaDoda>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://ww
w.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"><XPath>/dodas</XPath></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><DigestValue>47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=</DigestValue
></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>PLeNmY5ryu348507jd1P8DXMAEXQWg5ProRS9SU7tPDTVGjn33u4qwtU0HW1GJVwd3NpiGvjJzOonVR7gmoV8FbZtWG0IpLL8jy7PRAppZEupAAmGlFnLR10MPHKlvnsZIsiVstGn+TBKzx/EqNxztrfNJUUH8Huc65YPlq3TEA=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>yapCI4cdFFHP+pJ8LtCH8TxWpaPm
NwhFMy2/K6HmOEbyGYD+J2F3YcMaDCUnaG22t3V90p4bjEDQvhu+QLNL7JOQFs8pEOfRWL0OP0YglwZ0UnuK9umGV4hGxlpuj9q/JT1hJMhYJgIXwjNd1vw0mDeXmrJzBQQNX0ShZd8T4AM=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo></Signature>
Documento XML firmado con éxito!
```

The second output is:

```
    <mat:altaDoda xmlns:mat="http://impl.service.qrws.ce.siat.sat.gob.mx/siatbus/matce"><dodas><credenciales><!--Optional:--><ciec>
    <!--Optional:--><Usuario>ANOTHERTEST2TEST2</Usuario>
    <!--Optional:--><Contrasena>VMH94111</Contrasena></ciec>
<!--Optional:--><sellado><!--Optional:--><cadenaOriginalAA>kldffI
        L</cadenaOriginalAA><!--Optional:--><certificado64>kk9rtreljd</certificado64><!--Optional:--><firmado>||jkjkkkk|trtvl76767|jnkj3444||</firmado><!--Optional:--><serie>1234567890</serie></sellado></credenciales><!--1 or more repetitions:--><doda><!--Optional:--><datosGenerales><!--Optional:--><aduana>
        170</aduana><!--Optional:--><seccion>170</seccion><!--Optional:--><caat>123</caat><!--Optional:--><contenedores><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><contenedor><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><candados><!--Optional:--><valorCandado>valCandado01</valorCandado></candados><!--Optional:--><valorContenedor>v
        alContenedor01</valorContenedor></contenedor></contenedores><!--Optional:--><idTransporte>890zxc</idTransporte><!--Optional:--><fastId /><!--Zero or more repetitions:--><tipoOperacion>1</tipoOperacion></datosGenerales><!--Optional:--><pedimentos><!--1 or more repetitions:--><pedimento><!--Optional:-
        -><patenteAutorizacion>3904</patenteAutorizacion><!--Optional:--><documento>7100164</documento><!--Optional:--><numeroRemesa>2</numeroRemesa><!--Optional:--><dtaNiu>abc</dtaNiu><!--Optional:--><importeDifDolares>abc</importeDifDolares><!--Optional:--><importeEfectivoDolares>abc123</importeEfectivoDo
        lares><!--Optional:--><umc>abc</umc><!--Optional:--><articulo7>0</articulo7><!--Optional:--><cove>12345</cove></pedimento></pedimentos></doda></dodas></mat:altaDoda>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://ww
w.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"><XPath>/dodas</XPath></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><DigestValue>47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=</DigestValue
></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>PLeNmY5ryu348507jd1P8DXMAEXQWg5ProRS9SU7tPDTVGjn33u4qwtU0HW1GJVwd3NpiGvjJzOonVR7gmoV8FbZtWG0IpLL8jy7PRAppZEupAAmGlFnLR10MPHKlvnsZIsiVstGn+TBKzx/EqNxztrfNJUUH8Huc65YPlq3TEA=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>yapCI4cdFFHP+pJ8LtCH8TxWpaPm
NwhFMy2/K6HmOEbyGYD+J2F3YcMaDCUnaG22t3V90p4bjEDQvhu+QLNL7JOQFs8pEOfRWL0OP0YglwZ0UnuK9umGV4hGxlpuj9q/JT1hJMhYJgIXwjNd1vw0mDeXmrJzBQQNX0ShZd8T4AM=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo></Signature>
Documento XML firmado con éxito!
```

The first input has a tag value

```
<Usuario>TEST1TEST1</Usuario>
```

The second input has a tag value

```
<Usuario>ANOTHERTEST2TEST2</Usuario>
```

But has the same DigestValue

```
<DigestValue>47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=</DigestValue>
```

Comment: You're first and second inputs are identical...

Comment: Thanks for the annotation!

Comment: Both input are the same except for a tag. The first input is  **<Usuario>TEST1TEST1</Usuario>** The second input is: **<Usuario>ANOTHERTEST2TEST2</Usuario>**